# How to change colors in state machine diagram?

Tags: metapost, metauml

I've managed to change colors of classes in classes diagrams using

```
iClass.foreColor := (0.75, 1, 1);
```

but apparently

```
iState.forecolor := (0.75, 1, 1);
```

doesn't work. I can't find anything in the manuals and source is beyond my understanding.

Comment: Can you post a full working example rather than a snippet please?

Comment: Metapost suffix names are case sensitive, so `foreColor` is not the same as `forecolor`.

Comment: Well I was redacting my MWE and realised this was a case-issue. You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suffix names are case-sensitive, so you need to set `foreColor` not `forecolor`.

For the curious, here is a minimal example:

```
prologues:=3;
outputtemplate:="uml%c.eps";
input metauml;

beginfig(1);
iState.foreColor := (3/4,1,1);
State.s("Take order")();
drawObject(s);
endfig;
end
```

which produces:

[image]

The latest documentation is on [the MetaUML GitHub page](https://github.com/ogheorghies/MetaUML).